# Force in message_subscribe in odoov10 don't work

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I create method to update followers in calendar from project module.
First i wanna delete all exist followers and nest add new.
I have problem with "force=True" in documentation (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/mixins.html) is :

*force -- if True, delete existing followers before creating new one using the subtypes given in the parameters.*

So i change to true but my method only add new records without delete old.

```
@api.multi
def update_calendar_event(self):
    partner_list = []
    for follower in self.project_id.message_follower_ids:
        partner_list.append(follower.partner_id.id)
    partner_list.append(self.create_uid.partner_id.id)
    calendar_event = self.calendar_id.id
    self.calendar_id.message_subscribe(partner_ids=partner_list, force=True)
    self.test_field = calendar_event #debug
```

How to delete all exist records in calendar followers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i use to unsubscribe exist records before add new and that fix my problem.

```
@api.multi
def update_calendar_event(self):
    partner_list = []
    calendar_partner_list = []
    for follower in self.project_id.message_follower_ids:
        partner_list.append(follower.partner_id.id)
    partner_list.append(self.create_uid.partner_id.id)
    for follower in self.calendar_id.message_follower_ids:
        calendar_partner_list.append(follower.partner_id.id)
    self.calendar_id.message_unsubscribe(calendar_partner_list)
    self.calendar_id.message_subscribe(partner_list)
    self.test_field = [calendar_partner_list, partner_list] #debug
```